# Magento 2 : Add product.info.options.wrapper in custom module

Tags: magento2, custom-options

I want to add **product.info.options.wrapper** block in my custom module. I see in product view page that custom options render from this block.

So, I need to add this in my module. I tried to using by this code. But, it's not working.

```
$productData = $layout->createBlock('Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View', 'product.info.options.wrapper')->setProduct($product)->setTemplate('Magento_Catalog::product/view/options/wrapper.phtml')->toHtml();
```

How to implement this and render custom options?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Add in your xml file

```
          <referenceBlock name="product.info.options.wrapper" />
```

Comment: I want to get by specific product dynamically & it should be working as like working in product page.